# Paillier encryption of small integers to 32-bit integers

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I want to encrypt very small integers in the range `0-44` using the [Paillier cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem). Is there a way to select `p`, `q` (`g=n+1` anyway) and mostly `r` in such a way that I can guarantee that the encrypted values are still 32-bit integers?

Also, I have trouble understanding how to select `r`. According to wikipedia, the random $r \in \mathbb Z^{*}_{n} $. How can I implement this in a programming language e.g. Java when I will have to select random values of `r` for more than 100,000 such integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There are $2^{32}$ ciphertexts that fit into 32 bits. They will decrypt to $2^{32}$ random plaintexts uniformly distributed in the range $\{0, 1, \ldots, 2^{|n|}\}$. Since $|n| \gg 32$ for practical Paillier moduli, the probability of any 32-bit ciphertext encoding a plaintext in $\{0, \ldots, 44\}$ is negligibly small.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless whether input is small, $n$ must be large enough to avoid factorization. Next, $r$ must be sampled from a large space to avoid decryption by trial-and-error. Some crypto and big-numbers library (bouncycastle, openssl, crypto..) might be handy to implement such an algorithm. It would be safe to choose an implementation rather than write it from scratch.

Comment: As far as I know, bouncycastle has no Paillier implementation. And cryptopy does not either

Comment: bouncycastle has big numbers and random numbers to maybe implement Paillier algorithm with.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych `BigInteger` and `SecureRandom` are already part of the Java SE. Bouncy simply reuses those.

Comment: Except the implementation part, this answer is correct. If you adapt $n$, s.t. ciphertexts fit into the range of 32 bits, the factorization of $n$ is trivial. If you say $n^2 \approx 2^{32}$   (ciphertext space is mod $n^2$), prime factors of $n$ are around 8 bits. Even if you say you pick a larger $n$, and just have to find $r$,s.t. the ciphertext falls into this range, you can't make that work.